# Model factory is misbehaving in laravel tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

My laravel application is built on Laravel 8.12 and uses pest php for tests,

I have two tables groups and meetings and the their relation is one to many, where a meeting belongs to a group and group has many meetings,

I have a test case where I have to assert if a group can be created successful with it's meeting, the test case works well if I create only group without it's meeting but if I create the group with it's meeting using their relation the groups table contains two records of groups instead of one.

This is my test case when I create only group record

```
test('user see all meetings and registered groups successful', function () {

   Group::factory()->create();

    dd(Group::pluck('id'));

        actingWithPermission($this->user, $this->permission)
        ->get($this->route)
        ->assertViewHasAll([
            'totalRegistered' => 1,
            'totalMeetings' => 1,
        ]);
});
```

When I create the group record the groups table contains only one record as shown below

```
^ Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#3995
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => 36
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Test case when I create group and it's meeting record

```
test('user see all meetings and registered groups successful', function () {

   Group::factory()
   ->hasMeetings(1)
   ->create();

    dd(Group::pluck('id'));

        actingWithPermission($this->user, $this->permission)
        ->get($this->route)
        ->assertViewHasAll([
            'totalRegistered' => 1,
            'totalMeetings' => 1,
        ]);
});
```

When I dump the database contains two records of the groups instead of 1 as shown below:

```
^ Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#1847
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => 36
    1 => 37
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

This is one to many relation ship between group and meetings

```
 public function meetings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Meeting::class);
    }
```

How can I fix this?